# Mockito, how to return HTTP status from void method?

Tags: java, spring, mockito

I use
@ResponseStatus annotation

```
    @PostMapping
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public void create(@RequestBody @Valid RestaurantCreationDTO restaurantCreationDTO,
                   BindingResult bindingResult) {
    if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        throwExceptionIfBindingResultHasErrors(bindingResult);
    }
    restaurantService.create(restaurantCreationDTO);
}
```

But how can I test this method with mockito? I want to test if it's returning HttpStatus.CREATED.

Comment: It’s static - hardcoded - testing it with Mockito would be silly.

Comment: if you are returning somehow the http status in the return statement based on how successful the resource creation is, you will be able to test through Mockito. based on your current code snipped, it seems almost redundant.

Comment: @vaibhavsahu
So the best I can do is just to test if the service is called?

Comment: @KlausKöhler yes, you can use Mockito.verify(mockObject, times(1)).someMethod("was called exactly one time");

Answer (score 0):

You will need for example to create a `@WebMvcTest` that allows you to test MVC Controllers. Check the example below:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(YourRestController.class)
public class YourRestControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Test
    public void yourTest() throws Exception {
       mvc.perform(get("/api")
         .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
         .andExpect(status().isCreated());
    }
}
```

For more details check https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing#unit-testing-with-webmvctest.

Comment: I've done it, but can't really test void method with mockito

Comment: Can you please add your test code to the answer? Thanks.